# How to show HTML snapshot to crawlers

Tags: php, ajax

I'm running a website that uses AJAX to populate products from the database. Now I want to make this site crawlable for searchenginge's. I'v read this post on google webmasters [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/). But I have no clue how to make this work in my application. I just don't see how to apply this on my application without rewriting big parts of the code. Hopefully someone of you guys might give me some tips.

**My application**

URL: `www.mysite.com/productcategory/category1/`

This URL show products from category1 and a AJAX call creates the HTML. There are no special URL parameters. This is done because there is pagination. Clicking on the next page executes the same AJAX script but now it returns products for the next page. The URL will be modified (with jQuery history) to: 

`www.mysite.com/productcategory/category1/?page=2`

Clicking on the `next page` button a script called `get_products.ajax.php` and all parameters (like page=2) are send by a `POST`. So the call to the `get_products.ajax.php` is always the same, no parameters in the URL. Also a lot of information is stored in sessions to limit the number of database queries. So the list of products where the `get_product.ajax.php` is looking in, is a JSON string in a session.

**Crawlable**

To make the site crawlable, I need to create a snapshot of the HTML generated by the AJAX call. This all make's sence, but I have no clue of how I can show this content to Google in stead of the default AJAX content.

I'm staring at this issue all morning but I just don't see where I need to change things in my code...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is adding `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` between `<head></head>` tags on all your pages where you are using AJAX calls. In your case this means you should add this meta tag to the template which is used for rendering `www.mysite.com/productcategory/category1/`.

This will cause crawler will ask your page with `?_escaped_fragment_=` argument. Your task is to handle request with this parameter and return rendered page to the crawler.

For rendering you can use PhantomJS, https://prerender.io/ or something else.